# Filtering items in SharePoint list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter

I've got a SharePoint list with the following columns:

- City: eg. London, New York, Milan
- Visit Type: Business, Leisure
- Date: date visited

There could be multiple city visits of the same type, but the dates would be different.

*Sample Data*:

| City | Visit Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Business | 2021-01-15 |
| Paris | Leisure | 2020-12-30 |
| London | Business | 2020-08-10 |
| London | Leisure | 2020-07-06 |
| New York | Business | 2019-06-05 |

**I would like to create a View for this list that shows only the latest Business trips per each location.**

So using the sample data above, I would like to see a view that displays this:

| City | Visit Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Business | 2021-01-15 |
| New York | Business | 2019-06-05 |

I know you can edit the view to show only the rows which are of the "Business" visit type, but I don't know how to group it by City *and* display only the latest Date.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a sort on **Date column**, then limit the **count of the item** to be show in the view. By this you can see top 5 or 10 visits.

Also you can try to group by City column so it will show top date visit per city group.

Comment: I'm looking to only display the latest visit _per location_.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is impossible to display only one item with latest Date. You can group by city on Edit view page or in the view directly.
[image]
[image]

Then you can sort by Date in descending order, the first item is the one with the latest Date.
[image]

Comment: This is also the closest thing I could achieve.